# VideoCapture dosnt read from webcam openCV2.4.0 linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, webcam

I am trying to do some computer video by reading the webcam stream in openCV. I've tried with both the internal webcam and an external usb webcam which both are working great with programs like camorama, streamer etc.

part of my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "pic_manipulation.hpp"
#include "colorDetector.h"
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


int main ( int argc, char **argv ){
    string file="../test.avi";
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);//les video
    if(!capture.isOpened()){
        cout <<"could not read file"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }   
    double rate=capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    bool stop(false);
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("Extract frame");
    int delay=1000/rate;
    while(!stop){
        if(!capture.read(frame))break;
        cv::imshow("Extract frame", frame);
        sleep(delay/1000);
        if(cv::waitKey(delay)>=0){
            cout<<"stop"<<endl;
            stop=true;
            capture.release();
        }
        cout<< "one loop finished"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the program I dont get any errors or warnings, it just returns at if(!capture.isOpened()) (Or if i skip the isOpened it returns at the next if(...)). 
It reads video files with no problem at all. Anyone know if it is some bug with my install of opencv or if it is the linux webcam setting that's causing the problem?
I am using linux mint and building the project with cmake/g++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by installing openCV following this excellent guide: [A Comprehensive Guide to Installing and Configuring OpenCV 2.4.2 on Ubuntu](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/)

I suspect that I didnt set the right configurations for building ffmpeg, v4l on a 64 bit platform as specified in the above guide. Anycase, it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

Take another look at your code:

```
cv::VideoCapture capture(0);      // open the default camera
if(!capture.isOpened())           // check if it succeeded
{
  //...
}
```

The fact that `isOpened()` fails for index `0` tells your that it couldn't open the default camera. Since you have other cameras connected to your computer, you could also try passing `1`, `2`, `3`, ...

It's always good to [check the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#videocapture) and understand what each of these methods do and return.

[Here is a list of supported webcams](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS), some of your cameras might not be supported by OpenCV. That could explain why the default camera doesn't work.

Comment: I might have forgot to say that I have tried different inputs for the VideoCapture constructor (0,1,2,3...), with no luck. The internal and usb camera show up as video0 and video1 in /dev/ . Could it be that none of the two cameras are supported? (I'm using an acer timeline3030T with built in camera and an Logitech something usb webcam)

Comment: It could be. Try passing `-1` as parameter.

Comment: -1 didnt help either. Funny thing is that I can read both the cameras with the python binding for opencv. So I guess Im doing something wrong with my C++ program

Comment: If your C++ code is returning on `!capture.isOpened()`, I don't think there's much you can do.